# Date format wrong stored in the database

Tags: php

I try to store two dates in the database but it becomes another format.
To put in the date, I use dd-mm-yyyy

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks, Benny

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['newEvent'])) {

    session_start();

    //$eventName = $_POST['SelCatName'];
    $eventSDate = $_POST['Event-StartDate'];
    $eventSTime = $_POST['Event-StartTime'];
    $eventEDate = $_POST['Event-EndDate'];
    $eventETime = $_POST['Event-EndTime'];
    $eventDescription = $_POST['Event-Description'];
    $catIDs = $_POST["SelCatName"];
    $catID = explode("-", $catIDs);


$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO event (eventName, eventSdate, eventSTime, eventEdate, eventETime, eventDescription, catID)Values('{$catID [1]}', '{$eventSDate}', '{$eventSTime}', '{$eventEDate}', '{$eventETime}', '{$eventDescription}', '{$catID[0]}')");

header('Location: eventOK.php');
}
```

?>

Comment: MySQL stores date in format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: have you got "dd-mm-yyyy" format string in $_POST['Event-StartDate']? and mysql stores yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: You should read up on sql injection. And what does the table structure look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database will store the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

So you need to change your date to that format by using the below code

```
$eventSDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Event-StartDate']));
```

**Providing wrong format will add '1970-01-01' to database**

Comment: With pleasure. Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

before storing date into database just:

```
$eventSDate = date("Y-m-d" , strtotime($_POST['Event-StartDate'])) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL stores date in format `yyyy-mm-dd` and time in format `hh:mm:ss`

So you will have to convert your date and time in this format

```
$eventSDate = isset($_POST['Event-StartDate']) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Event-StartDate'])) : '' ;
$eventSTime = isset($_POST['Event-StartTime']) ? date('H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['Event-StartTime'])) : '' ;
$eventEDate = isset($_POST['Event-EndDate']) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Event-EndDate'])) : '' ;
$eventETime = isset($_POST['Event-EndTime']) ? date('H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['Event-EndTime'])) : '' ;
```